# Efficiently Compress Archives in Powershell as a background process

Tags: powershell, 7zip, persistent

I have a powershell script running in a PowerShell session that listens for files in a directory.  When a user drops a sub-directory or file into the listened folder ('toZip'), powershell calls 7Zip4PowerShell: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/7Zip4Powershell/1.9.0
and generates a .zip file in the zipOut folder.  The original file is then moved to the 'toDelete' folder and the user can check on the data the next day and move the .zip file off the server and delete their uncompressed data.

The problem is that this PowerShell script /or session appears to time out after a few days.  If I have multiple 1TB sub directories to compress, it will timeout at the second or third sub directory and there is no way of knowing this unless it's obvious that the qeue isn't moving anymore.

I duplicated this script for 4 locations because it was the easiest way for me to get going, and I tested the script.  For a few days, things work fine (it takes over a day to zip 1 TB to a single file), but then after a while the program hangs and appears to keep running in the task manager although nothing is contributed to the incomplete .zip file at this point.  I'm not sure if there is a certain file type that is causing the problem, but if I manually run 7zip on a given file, I can compress just fine.

```
$folder3 = 'H:\Shares\Data3\toZip'
$filter3 = '*.*'                             
$destinationZip3 = 'H:\Shares\Data3\ZipOut'
$destinationDelete3 = 'H:\Shares\Data3\toDelete'
$logPath3 = 'H:\Shares'
$fsw3 = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder3, $filter3 -Property @{
 IncludeSubdirectories = $false              
 NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, DirectoryName, LastWrite'
}
$onCreated3 = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw3 Created -SourceIdentifier FileHZipped -Action {
 $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
 $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
 $baseName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($name)
Write-Host “The base name is ‘$baseName’ ”
 $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
 $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
 Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" –fore green
 Compress-7Zip -Path $path -ArchiveFileName "$($destinationZip3)\$($baseName).zip" -Format Zip
 Write-Host “The file ‘$($destinationZip3)\$($name)’ was zipped at $timeStamp”
 Out-File –FilePath “$($logPath3)\logZip.txt” –Append –InputObject “The file ‘$($destinationZip3)\$($baseName)’ was zipped at $timeStamp”
 Move-Item $path -Destination $destinationDelete3 -Force -Verbose # Force will overwrite files with same name
}
```

Smaller files zip fine and the data is moved to the appropriate folders.  Its just that larger sub directories cause the program to time out.  I'm not sure what resources I should access to further debug this issue.  Any links or pointers to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know where it hangs? At `Compress-7Zip`? You can download and run process monitor from sysinternal. It's the easiest tool I know that can give you some insight into what might be going on. If that doesn't tell you anyhting, next up is to take a memory dump and analyze that with WinDbg.

Comment: Thanks.  I ran procmon over the weekend, but I forgot to set the log.  Procmon crashed at a thread create call -- it didn't let me save the output though.  I'll need to RTFM first and then run it again -- thanks for the tip though!

Comment: So today I found that it's hanging between the Compress-7Zip and write-host.  The process monitor shows the powershell app stops sending read and write requests (the compression part), but when I press ctrl+c in powershell, things pick up, and process continues.  One curious detail is that the timeStamp is fixed to the moment when I had dropped all the files (I'm zipping 10 folders here) which began a week ago.  I assumed it would update as each file was loaded, but I see I misunderstood the code I wrote.  OK, more RTFM time for me, I think I'm getting somewhere though.

Comment: with this knowledge I'd use Process Explorer to look at the threads of your process and examine their stack trace. I assume the dll gets loaded into the powershell process itself so any threads created should be visible in the powershell process. If that doesn't give any obvious pointers as to what it's waiting on, you can run `procmon -ma <PID>` to create a dumpfile of the entire process and analyze that with Windbg.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  I updated Windows a few times since October and now I can't trigger any errors from the power shell script.  I won't be able to run any more tests on this system because I'm leaving my position at work pretty soon, but the comments were super helpful.  I hate leaving mysteries out there, but nothing is breaking anymore.